# SELECT count with condition inside CASE

Tags: mysql, count, case

I am trying to count certain rows of a table when a condition is met. Below is an example of what am trying to do.

```
SELECT (CASE
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE (tb1.col IS NULL OR tb1.col=1) THEN 1
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE tb1.col=2 THEN 2
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE tb1.col=3 THEN 3
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE tb1.col=4 THEN 4
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE tb1.col=5 THEN 5
        WHEN COUNT(*)<9 WHERE tb1.col=6 THEN 6
    END)
WHERE tb1.id=X
```

I know its not exactly working like that, but I was wondering, since I have to make 12 more WHEN.. THEN, if there is another way to do it. Basically am trying to count rows that meet a condition and check if there are less than 9. Repeat that 17 more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your data by `tb1.col` and get the counts of each group. Then find the first value that has less than 9.

```
SELECT MIN(col) AS val
FROM (
    SELECT IFNULL(tb1.col, 1) AS col, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM yourTable AS tb1
    WHERE tb1.id = X
    GROUP BY col
) x
WHERE count < 9
```

Comment: Seems like a good way to do it, but after running it I got, _Every derived table must have its own alias._

Comment: I hope you searched for that error message and found the solution before I edited my answer to show it.

Comment: haha I did, I dont know but it made think you must be a really good person saying that, I know it might not correlate at all, just made me think about it :p

Comment: Just because I have lots of rep doesn't mean I don't make mistakes.

Comment: As a side note: I noticed that it returns different results for the null and the col=1. What I mean by that is that they should count as one and not seperate. So 3x col=null col and 8x col=1, should return as 2, not 1 cause 3+8>9

Comment: `IFNULL(tb1.col, 1)` should make null the same as 1. Are you sure the column is null, not an empty string?